# How to optimize Firebase Firestore using Flutter Package in StreamBuilder?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to reduce the number of read usage in FirebaseFirestore. As I am trying to load the FireStore Data in StreamBuilder. StreamBuilder connects with FireStore everytime whenever the app restarts, it is increasing the number of read usage. Is there a way to optimize the Firestore read usage?

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'LoginScreen.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'FlutterFire Samples',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme:
          ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.indigo, brightness: Brightness.dark),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  //Initializing
  final CollectionReference _products =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('products');

  final _productsStream = _products.snapshots();

  // Source can be CACHE, SERVER, or DEFAULT.

  final TextEditingController _nameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _priceController = TextEditingController();

  Future<void> _create([DocumentSnapshot? documentSnapshot]) async {
    await showModalBottomSheet(
        isScrollControlled: true,
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext ctx) {
          return Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 20,
                left: 20,
                right: 20,
                bottom: MediaQuery.of(ctx).viewInsets.bottom + 20),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                TextField(
                  controller: _nameController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Name'),
                ),
                TextField(
                  keyboardType:
                      const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  controller: _priceController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Price',
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('Create'),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    //var i = 0;
                    //for (i = i; i < 10000; i++) {
                    // final String name;
                    // final double? price;
                    double.tryParse(_priceController.text);
                    // if (price != null) {
                    await _products.add({
                      "name": _nameController.text,
                      "price": _priceController.text
                    });
                    // }

                    _nameController.text = '';
                    _priceController.text = '';
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    //}
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
  }

  Future<void> _update([DocumentSnapshot? documentSnapshot]) async {
    if (documentSnapshot != null) {
      _nameController.text = documentSnapshot['name'];
      _priceController.text = documentSnapshot['price'].toString();
    }

    await showModalBottomSheet(
        isScrollControlled: true,
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext ctx) {
          return Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 20,
                left: 20,
                right: 20,
                bottom: MediaQuery.of(ctx).viewInsets.bottom + 20),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                TextField(
                  controller: _nameController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Name'),
                ),
                TextField(
                  keyboardType:
                      const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                  controller: _priceController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Price',
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('Update'),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    final String name = _nameController.text;
                    final double? price =
                        double.tryParse(_priceController.text);
                    if (price != null) {
                      await _products
                          .doc(documentSnapshot!.id)
                          .update({"name": name, "price": price});
                      _nameController.text = '';
                      _priceController.text = '';
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
  }

  Future<void> _delete(String productId) async {
    await _products.doc(productId).delete();

    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
        content: Text('You have successfully deleted a product')));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
        // stream: _products.snapshots(),
        stream: _productsStream,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> streamSnapshot) {
          if (streamSnapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: streamSnapshot.data!.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
                    streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index];
                return Card(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(documentSnapshot['name']),
                    subtitle: Text(documentSnapshot['price'].toString()),
                    trailing: SizedBox(
                      width: 100,
                      child: Row(children: [
                        IconButton(
                          onPressed: () => _update(documentSnapshot),
                          icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                            onPressed: () => _delete(documentSnapshot.id)),
                      ]),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          }
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => _create(),
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: To increase the chances that we can help you optimize, it'd be really helpful if you can show how you currently implemented the reads from Firebase. Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have updated the question and added my implementation. Can you please help me with the possible solution. Thank you!

Comment: Oof... that's a lot more code than I was hoping for. Are you sure this is the **minimum** that is needed to reproduce the context you're asking our help on? On Flutter apps, it really helps if you remove any UI elements that are not related to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `final _productsStream = _products.snapshots();` every time the app starts, so that will have to connect to the server to check for snapshots. Even if you have [disk caching](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) enabled and there are documents in the local cache, the SDK will connect to the server to check if there are updates to those documents. If there are no updates, the number of document reads caused by this should be fairly minimal though.

The only alternative is to get (not listen) the content from the cache, as shown in [getting data from the cache](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#source_options). But in that case you won't know if the `QuerySnapshot` you get it stale, as that would require to check with the server - which causes documents to be possibly read there and thus be charged.

If you regularly find many clients readying a bunch of the same documents, you can consider shipping that bundle of document to clients outside of the client-to-server SDK by using [data bundles](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/bundles). For a more elaborate example of this, see the Firebase documentation on [serving bundled Firestore content from a CDN](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/serve-bundles).